# Context.SaveChanges in Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

This is basic winform application, no service or anything in-between. I am fetching some records from db using Entity Framework. Below code is in a class called PersonRepository.

```cs
var obj = Context.Persons.Where(u=>u.Id==20);
obj.RegisterDate = obj.RegisterDate.ToMountainStandardTime();
return obj;
```

ToMountainStandardTime is an extension method for date type.

Now after I pull this record, and display to UI. User does some action on screen, And based on requirements insert record in another table called "Activity". User don't need to save anything back in Person table.

After doing their things, like this

```cs
Context.Activities.Add(newActivityObject);
Context.SaveChange();
```

Both methods are in same class. Along with adding a new object in activity table, it also update the register date  of selected person class.
I know the reason, this Context object initialize in constructor of PersonRepository class and being used by all the methods in this class.

Most of my experience is using this via restful services where I don't need much to worry about such things because for every request we create new instances of context.

I can simply handle this by Detach the object from context before editing it like this

```cs
Context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

But want to know if there is some better way to handle this?

Comment: You can change to singleton context.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices to consider. Firstly, entities either can only be relied upon to be valid within the scope of the DbContext they were read, or they need to be detached and re-attached to transition between DbContext boundaries.

To keep entities scoped within their DbContext, your options are:

1. Long-lived (i.e. Singleton) DbContext.
2. Short-lived, project entities to POCO containers and re-load entities on-demand as needed.

The third option is to use short-lived DbContexts, but then manually manage detaching and re-attaching the entities.

I never recommend this third option as it is prone to errors and encourages issues like stale data overwrites. It's neat in concept, but more often than not becomes a repeated source of headaches in practice.

For smaller applications that themselves have relatively short runtime lives, a long-lived DbContext can be a simple to implement option. The biggest negatives of a long-lived DbContext are:

- Having a context alive for extended periods of time can mean performance degrades over time as more entities are cached. The assumption that cached entities are better for performance can be misplaced as time to perform operations against entities (updates/inserts) increase as the cache grows, since EF will look through the cache for entity references that might be associated to new/changed entity values.
- Data that the context is loading will become stale if multiple instances are running, or external processes can modify data state. By default EF will return cached copies which must manually be reloaded if suspected of being stale.

For larger applications, or long-running applications I would strongly lean towards using short-lived DbContext that rely on POCO ViewModels/DTOs for view-duration data state. This means leveraging Projection via `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` to load relevant data from entities on demand to pass to views, then reload entities by ID, and transfer across data or perform actions with changed state values during updates after verifying Row Version Numbers / Timestamps to detect possible stale data state. Reloading an entity and it's related data by PK is extremely quick.

Not only does this avoid the complexity/mess of trying to juggle detached entities, (and reloading data state anyways to guard against stale overwrites) but it can lead to more optimal data read operations and index utilization for many scenarios, especially things like search results which only need a few values from specific tables rather than reading entire entity graphs. A cardinal sin of passing Entities to views is attempting to avoid extra data reads by avoiding eager loading and disabling lazy loading to leave "unused" relationships as #null, or even populating Entity class objects with just a few fields to serve as a view model with `.Select` which leads to errors or bad assumptions/overwrites in later code. An Entity should always represent a complete (or complete-able) state of the data row. Dual-purposing entities to serve as both data domain state and view state is asking for trouble. Methods expecting an entity should never need to be concerned about whether they are getting a complete entity or a partially complete one.